# I/O operation on closed file only with large file (>3M)

Tags: python, django

I use django and save uploaded file with the same code:

```
destination = open(directory + newfilename, 'wb+')
for chunk in docfile.chunks():
    destination.write(chunk)
    destination.close()
```

But when I upload large file (~3M and more) I get this error:

```
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

On `destination.write(chunk)` line.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Indent is vital in python... Please make it right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you closed the file in the for loop..
Try to put close outside.

```
    destination = open(directory + newfilename, 'wb+')
    for chunk in docfile.chunks():
        destination.write(chunk)
    destination.close()
```

Comment: I did not even notice that! Thank you. :)